# Can't reindex Catalog Category/Product Index via admin

Tags: configuration, admin, indexing

I have a Magento Enterprise 1.13 installation that won't allow me to trigger reindexing the Catalog Category/Product Index and other indexes through the admin.  The "Reindex Data" Action is not available even though it is set to Update on Save. It does seem to be automatically reindexing on save but does not on import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bigger part of indexes are now meant to run in background.
You have also option to schedule cron indexing.
See http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee113-indexing for more details.
There is no proof way to manually re-index via Admin

Answer (score 5):

Ensure you are using a MySQL version that supports [Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html), first. As 1.13 EE uses them to automatically insert the data upon saving from the EAV tables to the flat tables.

Double check that the triggers exist in the database itself, especially if this was an upgrade.

Example of a trigger, first portion says on each update of table X do the following on tables X, Y, Z, etc.  Mostly I've noticed these triggers are for `UPDATE`,`DELETE`,`INSERT`

`AFTER UPDATE ON db.catalog_product_entity_int
FOR EACH ROW`

```
BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `cataloginventory_stock_status_cl` (`product_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`product_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_index_cl` (`product_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_index_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_flat_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);

END
```

My gripe as well is why was the option removed from the admin? Especially since its obviously possible doing indexing via `php shell/indexer.php reindexall` without issues. I have confirmed with Magento themselves that should still function the same.

As Petar mentioned, familiarize yourself with the list of items that *Require* a full reindex should also help:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee113-indexing#appendix

Comment: Also, a side note: If you use Magento's Built-in Backup, Triggers will be missing: https://github.com/tim-reynolds/Envalo_Backup

Answer (score 0):

I bet it might be caused by wrong permisson set to tmp folder.
Check /var/locks/ folder permissions and see if there are any files.
You should find there:

```
index_process_1.lock
index_process_2.lock
...
index_process_9.lock
```

Check date of modification. If proper permission are set (755) just remove those files and try to re run indexing.

Answer (score -2):

refer this link to reindex products in magento easily- 
http://www.codetweet.com/magento/reindexing-magento-programmaticaly/

Comment: Single link answers are not the best. explain a little what is found at the end of that url

Comment: the post on above link shows how to reindex products data in magento.You can find a well written php script and execute the script via command line to reindex

Comment: that link is broken... well that site is at least... it says "Error establishing a database connection";