# Reduce the size of the CL tables

Tags: database, enterprise-1.14, mysql-indexes

I would like to reduce the size of the _cl tables in EE 1.14

```
 catalog_product_index_price_cl                |    1572.00 |
| catalogsearch_fulltext_cl                     |    1512.00 |
| catalog_product_flat_cl                       |     977.00 |
| cataloginventory_stock_status_cl              |     604.00 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here :

[Mechanics of the new Changelog Tables (ex: catalog_category_product_cat_cl)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3840/mechanics-of-the-new-changelog-tables-ex-catalog-category-product-cat-cl)

The Enterprise_Mview module already has the ability to clean these tables. It takes the latest version_id for each table from enterprise_mview_metadata and deletes any rows with a version_id lower than that. You can enable index cleaning by going to System > Configuration > (ADVANCED section) > Index Management and setting Enable Scheduled Cleanup to Yes under Index Clean Schedule.

Thanks to https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/5694/tyler-v