# Changelog tables and optimizations

Tags: magento-enterprise, enterprise-1.14

In newer versions of Enterprise Magento ships with change log tables (See [Mechanics of the new Changelog Tables (ex: catalog_category_product_cat_cl)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/3840/158) for more information on how they work). Now these tables can become large over time, for example my most recent dump from a client has the following:

```
+------------------------------------+------------+
| Table                              | Size in MB |
+------------------------------------+------------+
| catalogsearch_fulltext_cl          |     911.00 |
| catalog_product_index_price_cl     |     728.00 |
| cataloginventory_stock_status_cl   |     709.00 |
| catalog_product_flat_cl            |     208.75 |
| catalog_category_product_index_cl  |      59.59 |
| catalog_category_flat_cl           |      53.59 |
| enterprise_url_rewrite_category_cl |      48.58 |
| catalog_category_product_cat_cl    |      48.58 |
| enterprise_url_rewrite_product_cl  |       2.52 |
| enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect_cl |       0.09 |
+------------------------------------+------------+
```

Now there is a cron that can be enabled to clean these tables up. This can be done via the `System > Configuration > (ADVANCED section) > Index Management`. After running this cron I would expect to see these tables shrink in size but running the same query after returns the following:

```
+------------------------------------+------------+
| Table                              | Size in MB |
+------------------------------------+------------+
| catalogsearch_fulltext_cl          |     996.00 |
| catalog_product_index_price_cl     |     728.00 |
| cataloginventory_stock_status_cl   |     723.48 |
| catalog_product_flat_cl            |     208.75 |
| catalog_category_product_index_cl  |      59.59 |
| catalog_category_flat_cl           |      53.59 |
| enterprise_url_rewrite_category_cl |      48.58 |
| catalog_category_product_cat_cl    |      48.58 |
| enterprise_url_rewrite_product_cl  |       2.52 |
| enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect_cl |       0.02 |
+------------------------------------+------------+
```

What the heck is happening? For example `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` has increased from 911MB to 996MB after cleaning the table?

Answer (score 3):

While looking into the content of the tables I noticed that the size goes up but the content actually decreases. Let's keep the example of the `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` table.

Before the clean it has 31748125 rows.
After the clean it has 192892 rows.

So after the cleaning process I ran `OPTIMIZE TABLE` across all the `_cl` tables and then the size was as follows:

```
+------------------------------------+------------+
| Table                              | Size in MB |
+------------------------------------+------------+
| catalog_category_product_cat_cl    |      54.58 |
| catalogsearch_fulltext_cl          |       7.52 |
| cataloginventory_stock_status_cl   |       7.52 |
| catalog_product_index_price_cl     |       1.52 |
| enterprise_url_rewrite_category_cl |       0.02 |
| catalog_product_flat_cl            |       0.02 |
| catalog_category_product_index_cl  |       0.02 |
| catalog_category_flat_cl           |       0.02 |
| enterprise_url_rewrite_redirect_cl |       0.02 |
| enterprise_url_rewrite_product_cl  |       0.02 |
+------------------------------------+------------+
```

How this is much better results and a more manageable size database.