# Magento1 change-logs cleanup

Tags: indexer, ee-1.14

I've end up having the following query:

```
SELECT 
  entity_id,
  count(version_id) as number_of_versions, 
  max(version_id) as max_version
FROM catalog_product_flat_cl
GROUP BY entity_id
ORDER BY number_of_versions DESC
```

giving the following output

```
entity_id  number_of_versions   max_version
    19305                 297       2476959
    20084                 294       2479871
    17728                 293       2471572
    22541                 292       2483741
    22543                 292       2483743
    22131                 292       2471939
    19306                 291       2476960
    18660                 290       2474991
    18674                 289       2475023
    18671                 287       2475020
    18662                 287       2474993
    22387                 287       2478594
    17850                 286       2472048
    17727                 286       2471539
```

which seem like something is terribly wrong.

**So the question is:** it safe to store that in a temp table and delete per `entity_id` where version is smaller then the max version? Like this

```
CREATE TABLE _temp_table (
  entity_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  number_of_versions INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  max_version INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (entity_id));

INSERT INTO _temp_table
SELECT 
  entity_id,
  count(version_id) as number_of_versions, 
  max(version_id) as max_version
FROM catalog_product_flat_cl
GROUP BY entity_id
ORDER BY number_of_versions DESC

DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_cl
USING _temp_table AS tmp
WHERE catalog_product_flat_cl.entity_id = tmp.entity_id
  AND catalog_product_flat_cl.version_id < tmp.max_version;


DROP TABLE _temp_table;
```

*NOTE:* I'm not asking for errors in my SQL code above, I'm asking if the general idea of deleting items by hands from the change-log tables is ok.

*NOTE:* the deletion code above is untested, if you decide to use it on your Magento database - take backup first.

kind of related topics
[Changelog tables and optimizations](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/165441/158)
https://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/magento-enterprise-index-lesson-329